# Cannot find package com.twocheckout.TwocheckoutCharge

Tags: maven, repository, 2checkout

I want to use 2Checkout-java library for JSF WAR application. I configured this into `pom.xml` file:

***Dependency:***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twocheckout</groupId>
    <artifactId>twocheckout-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

***Maven repository:***

```
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-releases</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

But when I try to compile the code I get:

> Cannot find package com.twocheckout.TwocheckoutCharge.

I checked the jar file into repository and I saw that the size of the jar is only 2.1 KB!

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/twocheckout/twocheckout-java/0.1.0/

Maybe I'm missing some configuration? I checked the content of the jar file I don't see any Java .class files. Did you had similar case?